# Google index MVC URIs in a long-page context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search

I have a long page comprised with a set of modules with their own URI

Example

Page URI

http://mysite/index/product

Module URIs

http://mysite/index/product/specifications
http://mysite/index/product/features

Now what I would like to do, is when a user searches for "features", then Google would display the content from the individual module in the search results, but when the user clicked the link, it would actually take them to the "features" section within the context of the "product" combined page.

I've tried a test using a canonical link back from the module URI to the main page but Google simply indexes the content in the full page.

How would one approach this?  I'm sure it's possible?